# What should ConfigureAuth settings be for mixed authentication? (Standard Login Page and OpenId challenge)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, single-sign-on, openid

The system has two ways users can be authenticated:

1. Standard login form
2. Button on login form which issues openid challenge (SSO)

In the code below including AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie to app.UseCookieAuthentication breaks SSO (2 above). The page is redirected to the redirectUrl but does not seem to have the token or be authenticated and so is redirected to Login page. Standard login (1) works fine however.

When AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie is removed, SSO  (2) works fine but standard login (1) no longer works and the user is redirected back to login form.

I've tried reordering app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication before app.UseCookieAuthentication but that did not help.

```cs
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            //configurable in web config - default to 30 minutes
            int cookieTimeSpan = Settings.Default.AuthenticationTimeoutMinutes;

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    // I reckon this portion of code is checking the OpenID connect cookie against a cookie form expected by CMS.
                    // Because the style of cookie is different, the cookie is invalidated and the login process is invoked a second time, creating a loop.

                    // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                    // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser, int>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(cookieTimeSpan),
                        regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) =>
                            user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager),
                        getUserIdCallback: user =>
                        {
                            return user.GetUserId<int>();
                        })
                }
            });

            // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
            app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions()
                {
                    // Sets the ClientId, authority, RedirectUri as obtained from web.config
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    Authority = authority,
                    RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                    // PostLogoutRedirectUri is the page that users will be redirected to after sign-out. In this case, it is using the home page
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                    Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
                    // ResponseType is set to request the id_token - which contains basic information about the signed-in user
                    ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
                    // ValidateIssuer set to false to allow personal and work accounts from any organization to sign in to your application
                    // To only allow users from a single organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and 'tenant' setting in web.config to the tenant name
                    // To allow users from only a list of specific organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and use ValidIssuers parameter 
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = false
                    },
                    // OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications configures OWIN to send notification of failed authentications to OnAuthenticationFailed method
                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                    {
                        AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
                    },
                    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive
                }
            );
        }
```

Can anyone identify what the issue is please and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

Putting `app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie)` above `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication` resolved the issue.